# Producer Consumer Model Without Lock or Use Thread Safe Collections or Lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, locking

I have a scenario as following ;
One thread(say Updater Thread) periodically fetchs data from database and update shared static object according to values read from database.
Another thread/s read(say Reader Thread) aforementioned data.

It seems to me lock is not necessary because only one thread updates shared static object.So imagine that our reader thread happens to read the value of shared static object exactly halfway through a write.

It seems possible in this case to read some fields of shared static object in the middle of update,let's say Shared object has **total price decimal property**(128 bits) and when read happened **only the first or last 64 bits have been updated**!
Can it really happen ? Should I use lock for atomicy ? Or put my shared static object any thread safe collections and perform write and read operations on it  like concurrent dictionary ?

Comment: `It seems possible in this case to read some fields of shared static object in the middle of update,let's say Shared object has total price decimal property(128 bits) and when read happened only the first or last 64 bits have been update` Yes. Only aligned pointer-sized read/write operations are guaranteed to be atomic without synchronization

Comment: @KevinGosseI searched for  aligned pointer but didn't get what you mean.By the way if I use static concurrent dictionary and place object inside it and let write and read operations take place on that concurrent dictionary.Then writes becomes  atomic ?Does concurrent dictionary implements Monitor.Enter for the writing portion ? I searched for how concurrent dictionary becomes thread safe and  when to use over dictionary but I didn't really figure it out.

Comment: Do you update the static object by replacing it with another object, or by updating its properties one by one?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am updating properties one by one.I could replace object with another object but old data read doesn't matter for me because it's not a mission critical project, my biggest concern is torn read.

Comment: What types are the properties you are updating? Are there any `Decimal`s between them?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes

Answer (score 1):

Accessing shared state from multiple threads without synchronization can lead to data corruption. The safest and cleanest solution is to synchronize the access to the shared data, so that only one thread can access them at a time. Example:

```
public static class SharedState
{
    private static readonly object _locker = new object();

    private static Decimal _value1;
    public static Decimal Value1
    {
        get { lock (_locker) return _value1; }
        set { lock (_locker) _value1 = value; }
    }
}
```

This is enough for immutable types like the `Decimal`, but not enough if you have properties that are mutable containers like `List<T>`, that are not explicitly designed with thread-safety in mind.

Comment: What about first keeping object non static and putting it in a concurrent dictionary? Like ; 
 static   ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
//Update/Insert single writer thread
ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(1, object);
//Read multiple reader threads
ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(1, out itemValue2);

Comment: @erhan355 this is also a possibility. The `ConcurrentDictionary` uses locks internally.